# How to suppress/downgrade "Unknown resource" errors from Catalyst

Tags: perl, catalyst

By default, [Catalyst::Dispatch](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Catalyst-Runtime/lib/Catalyst/Dispatcher.pm) issues an error when an unknown resource (essentially a 404 error, by my understanding) is requested:

> Delegate the dispatch to the action that matched the url, or return a message about unknown resource

And my application's log file shows:

```
Mar 30 10:19:08 mail myapp: Unknown resource "user/soapCaller.bs"
Mar 30 16:20:38 mail myapp: Unknown resource "HTTP/1.1"
Mar 30 16:20:38 mail myapp: Unknown resource "index.php"
```

Arguably, this seems like a bug to me; a simple 404 shouldn't really be considered on par with with a "Unable to connect to database" *error*, but that's beside the point.  My question is:

**How can I change this behavior?**

I have had limited success with creating a simple **default()** action in Root.pm:

```
sub default : Private {
    my ( $self, $c ) = @_;
}
```

This successfully silences the errors to the log file, however, I have had no success writing my own log message/priority.  None of the following attempts to output my own warning succeed.

```
sub default : Private {
    my ( $self, $c ) = @_;
    warn "Foo\n";
    $c->log->debug('Bar');
    $c->log->warn('Baz');
}
```

So what is the best approach to define my own behavior for "unknown resources" in a Catalyst application?

Comment: Creating a root `default` is the right thing to do (although `sub default : Private` is ancient deprecated practice; `sub default : Path` will do just fine...). As for why your logger isn't working, we need more info. From what you've shown, there's no reason why it shouldn't.

Comment: @hobbs: I have switched to 'Path', and the behavior is the same. What additional info do you need regarding logging? I am using both the `LogWarnings` and `LogDispatch` plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had an auto() action, which ran before default(), and redirected to another page.

```
sub auto : Private {
    my ( $self, $c ) = @_;
    ...
    if ( ! $c->user_exists ) {
        $c->redirect( $c->uri_for('/login') );
    }
}
```

I was able to resolve this by adding:

```
    return 1 if $c->action eq 'default';
```

before the redirection.